# PyCharm (or IntelliJ with Python plugin): how to autogenerate placeholder for new class parameters?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Let's say we have a class:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str, c: str):
```

When we want to create an instance of this class:

```py
my_class = MyClass(a="a", b="b", c="c")
```

**Is there any feature/shortcut to autogenerate placeholders for all parameters?** For example, generating:

```py
my_class = MyClass(a=???, b=???, c=???)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature yet. Here is a relevant ticket in PyCharm issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41019/Code-completion-variant-pre-populating-keyword-arguments-of-a-call